# Comparing 2 Numbers in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, nested-if

I'm trying to compare 2 3-digit numbers. This is my current code using nested Ifs

```
If Mid(Num1, 1, 1) = Mid(Num2, 1, 1) Then  
'Check first number against first number

If Mid(Num1, 2, 1) = Mid(Num2, 2, 1) Then 
 'Check second number against second number


   If Mid(Num1, 3, 1) = Mid(Num2, 3, 1) Then  
    'Check third number against third number 

        Digits = 3

    Else

        Digits = 2

    End If
```

And this is just one small part of it. Also, I need to check the order in which they match as well. So whether it's an exact match, all 3 digits match in any order, or if 1 or 2 digits match in any order.

The problem is I have a lot of If statements using this method as I have to compare every combination of digits to check for a 1 digit, 2 digit, 3 digit, etc, match. Is there a better way?

Comment: Yes, you could introduce a loop. If you haven't already then it is time to study loops.

Comment: Also, might want to look into `Select Case` as well

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with these two numbers? There might be a much easier way than either loops or nested if statements.

Comment: Besides comparing the numbers, it seems you also need to know how many digits match. Is this correct? Do you also need to know the location of the digits that match? Obviously the more you require to know, the more complex this gets.

Comment: @user1992460 do the two numbers inputted always have to be same length, or one can be a 2 digit number and the other 3 digit one?

Comment: They will always be 3 digits each.

Comment: As an exercise, consider how your code would have to be structured in order to make it support 4-digit, 6-digit, n-digit combintions. The better the design, fewer bugs are potentially introduced by that change. I'd recommend you get your code working as intended, then put it up for review on [codereview.se] - you'll learn a ton of tricks from reviewers!

Comment: If you're only want matches for three-digit numbers and you're not afraid of memory consumption: Put all three-digit combinations in a Trie: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/
 It is VERY fast.

Comment: How would duplicate digits impact your expected result?  e.g. "007" and "360" - is that `1` or `2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be simplified to a `function` with a simple `for` loop

```
Private Function digitMatch(ByVal num1 as String, ByVal num2 as String) As Byte
 ' num1 and num2 are strings, because of presumption they can start with 0
 ' (i.e. 042 is valid 3 digit number format, otherwise they can be integers as well)

  Dim i As Byte
  Dim matches As Byte: matches = 0

  For i = 1 To Len(num1)
     If InStr(1, num2, Mid(num1, i, 1)) <> 0 Then
        matches = matches + 1
     End If
  Next i

  digitMatch = matches

End Function
```

> so eg. `digitMatch(023, 053)` would return `2`
>   or `digitMatch(123, 321)` would return `3`

Comment: I think this would fail with `digitMatch(032, 053)` as the _OP_ still expects 2, but your function would return 1.

Comment: I think that only checks them in one order though. So, for example if I have 123 and 321 this needs to return 3. This function wouldn't do that.

Comment: @ja72 yeah, question was posted before further information was revealed in comments, in process of editign the answer

Comment: @user1992460 check the answer now, now it does the digit match regarldess of the order

Comment: Yes, I believe this will work for my purpose, thank you!

Comment: @user1992460 Mark the answer as correct please then, so the question can be closed :) If you need further help, feel free to let me know

Comment: @Rawrplus Hey, this doesn't work for numbers with 2 of the same digits. For example if Num2 = 134 and Num1 = 112, then this will return 2 when it should return 1

Comment: @user1992460 This depends on which number you want for comparison and which as input. If you want `num2 = 134` and  `num1 = 112` to return 1, simply change the `ByVal num1` and `Byval num2` in function declaration and it should work

Comment: Well that's just reversing the problem haha anyways I made a small adjustment using string replace to delete the part of the number that matches on each iteration and it works now

Comment: @user1992460 That's not reversing the problem. You always need to one value to be compared to and one which you are comparing. It's mathematically impossible to have both.  But, obviously, you can let user pick which one is which, if you add one extra argument to function. Either way, guess you found your own solution, whatever floats your boat :)

Answer (score 1):

In my answer, I return the digits that match, so you can check if there are any and which ones. Also, it works with any number of digits.

```
Public Function CheckForMatch(ByVal curNum As String, ByVal winNumber As String) As String

    Dim i As Long, j As Long

     Dim hit As String
     hit = vbNullString

     For i = 1 To Len(curNum)
        j = InStr(1, winNumber, Mid(curNum, i, 1), vbTextCompare)
        If j > 0 Then
            hit = hit & Mid(curNum, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i

    CheckForMatch = hit
End Function

Public Sub Test()

    Dim check As String

    check = CheckForMatch("75214", "13672")

    If Len(check) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print "Numbers " & check & " are a match."
        ' 721
    Else
        Debug.Print "No match. Sorry."
    End If

End Sub
```

---

<sub>NOTE: The use of `InStr()` here was inspired by the answer [Rawplus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5512705/rawrplus) gave before me.</sub>

Comment: This is identical to my answer, only with a different output format.of the function

Comment: I was already typing my answer when you edited yours. I upvoted yours for the use of `InStr()` avoiding an inner loop. That was the only part I took from your answer.

Comment: Alright then. Afterall, don't take my comment as *"hey that's mine answer!"*, rather as a suggestion to avoid redundancy. Obviously, I can't complain given my answer was structured differently prior to the edit

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it will only work correctly if both 'curNum' and 'WinningNumber' are 3 digits long):

```
'straight match
If curNum = WinningNumber Then
    M = 3
    s = 3
'matched the first 2 straight
ElseIf InStr(1, WinningNumber, Left(curNum, 2)) > 0 Then
    M = 2
    s = 2
    If InStr(1, WinningNumber, Right(curNum, 1)) > 0 Then M = M + 1
'matched the last 2 straight
ElseIf InStr(2, WinningNumber, Right(curNum, 2)) > 0 Then
    M = 2
    s = 2
    If InStr(1, WinningNumber, Left(curNum, 1)) > 0 Then M = M + 1
'any other scenario
Else
    s = 0
    For i = 1 To 3
        n = Mid(WinningNumber, i, 1)
        If InStr(1, curNum, n) > 0 Then
            M = M + 1
        End If
    Next
End If

Debug.Print "Matched digits: " & M
Debug.Print "Straight: " & s
```

I'm sure there's a better way to do it but this was the easiest way for me to write it up quickly.

Comment: if then else else if else ... Ugly!

Comment: Hey! You're being very mean!

Comment: Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: I though your post was sarcastic, but judging but this reply I guess it wasn't. You hurt my feelings. It is ugly but it works and took me 2 minutes to write it for someone for free.

Comment: @peakpeak  what's that elitist attitude? He made a valid contribution. Yes the code may not be pretty,  but doesn't mean he should be shunned for it.

Comment: Give him suggestion on how to improve it, rather than just discourage him to code...